# How to create live shell-only ISO?

Tags: pxe, livedvd

All I need is bootable ISO file, which will run minimal linux and have in filesystem 2 files. One of them about 2GB, another one is my script. No GUI needed, only shell is enough. Eventually it should boot in PXE. Could you recommend me proper distribution/steps for that?

Comment: What all commands do you use in the script?

Comment: I should only use `dd` command, which should copy hard drive image from live DVD to PC hard drive.

Comment: See my answer. Ubuntu core would do the job for you, but if you want more fun, install the arch base system, which is more fun, and more closer to what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question related to Ubuntu, but to linux as Ubuntu is a distribution.

If I was you, I will install [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/) with all the tools I require in the USB. [Here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_Arch_Linux_on_a_USB_key) is the instructions.

But a simple solution would be [Ubuntu core](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Core).